Alternative Solution for Converting Word Shapes to Images for UserForm
I am trying to convert shapes embedded in a Word document into image files so that I can display them in a UserForm. My current approach involves using Microsoft Publisher to save the shapes as image files. While this method works, it takes a significant amount of time. Here is the code I am using:
Sub ShowImg()

    Dim ImgShape As Shape
    Dim ImgPath As String
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim TempFolderPath As String
    Dim OriginalWidth As Single
    Dim OriginalHeight As Single
    Dim P As Object

    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    
    TempFolderPath = ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    
    ImgPath = TempFolderPath & "temp_img_2.png"
    
    Set ImgShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes(2)
        With ImgShape
            OriginalWidth = .Width
            OriginalHeight = .Height
                            .Select
        End With
    
    Selection.Copy
    
    Set P = CreateObject("Publisher.Document")
    
    With P.Pages(1).Shapes.Paste(1)
        .LockAspectRatio = False
        .Width = OriginalWidth
        .Height = OriginalHeight
        .SaveAsPicture ImgPath
    End With
    P.Close
    
    Set P = Nothing
    
    'Kill ImgPath

End Sub

Is there a more efficient way to convert Word shapes into images? Any alternative approaches or improvements to reduce the execution time would be greatly appreciated.

Declare the P object as static: Static P As Object and then replace Set P = CreateObject("Publisher.Document") with If P Is Nothing Then Set P = CreateObject("Publisher.Document"). Finally, remove the P.Close and Set P = Nothing lines. This will avoid opening a new Publisher instance every time you do a new shape, at least for the current Word session.
